# webPages loading problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Using ASP.Net & C#

I want to run my web page in the internet explorer or firefox...

When i run the webpage, it was working in VS, but when i run the webpage in the ie it showing error as

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/Name/IIS/Detail

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="view.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
-^
```

I configured the IIS, then i run the *.html file it is displaying without any error but *.aspx file is not displaying.

*.html file is running in ie & firefox, but *.aspx file is not running in ie & firefox,

How to run my *.aspx webpages in internet explore or firefox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message comes **when you try to run the aspx file right in the browser** [opening .aspx with browser] without any server-side end-point or **when your IIS is not configured to deal with ASP.NET**. ASP.NET is a server-side technology which means the server executes the asp.net page when requested and renders the output browser back in a way that it can understand which is html,xhtml, javascript etc.

> **Why this Message comes ?**

When an asp.net file is received in browser as-is [without having the page rendered into html], the browser treats it as an XML file and asp.net page markup is not found to be a valid XML file, hence the error.

> **Solution**

All you need to do is **host your asp.net application under a website or virtual directory in IIS and configure it to work with asp.net** and then request/run the .aspx file from browser with URL of your asp.net page as configured in the IIS.

You can find resources and information on how to configure IIS for asp.net **[here](http://learn.iis.net/)**.

Comment: Can you provide the steps for configure with asp.net

Comment: Explaining the entire config. process is beyond the scope of this asnwer. I recommend you start from here - http://learn.iis.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the files directly? That's not going to work.

If you've configured IIS properly, you should just be able to browse to `http://localhost/` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your ASP.Net may not be registered properly with IIS.
You need to run the aspnet_regiis -i command from the visual studio command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Check the windows features, is .NET installed?